# Foreach loop through XML tags named tag-1, tag-2, tag-3

Tags: php, xml, tags

How can one loop through XML structure with tags named like

```
<response>
<tag-1>
    <item>
        <id>106</id>
        <title>DG</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>105</id>
        <title>AC</title>
    </item>
</tag-1>
<tag-2>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>DjG</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>15</id>
        <title>AoC</title>
    </item>
</tag-2>
</response>
```

So I load xml with simplexml_load_file, then I tried with xml->children().

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $kat);
{
    var_dump($kat);
}
```

This has only returned the last element. So I can not loop through all of the tag-* elements.

Any help how to loop through all tags named tag-* will be very appreciated

Comment: it's working fine: https://eval.in/521226

Comment: you are right, it is working. Strange. I was trying to get this to work for more then an hour..

Comment: solved? Then you might delete your question.